# ThreadPoolExecutor returning error <Future at 0x1ba9696bb08 state=finished raised TypeError>

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor, geocode

I am trying to run a geocoding api function on a dataframe in parallel.
I am trying to divide the dataframe in fixed parts and run the geocoding function in parallel on it using ThreadPoolExecutor.

I have one function called split12(), which runs the geocoding function.

```
import censusbatchgeocoder as cg
from censusbatchgeocoder import geocode

def split12(i):
df = pd.read_csv(r'path\addressfile.csv')
df[i:i+2]["id"] = np.arange(len(df[i:i+2]))
df[i:i+2]["hashId"] = df[i:i+2].apply(generateHashKey , axis=1)
results = cg.geocode(df[i:i+2].to_dict("records"))
lii.append(results)
```

generateHashKey creates a hashkey (and it is working fine)

Then I am trying to execute the threadpool

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'path\addressfile.csv')
ilist = [i for i in range(0,len(df),2)]
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    rlist = executor.submit(split12,ilist)
```

When I try to print rlist, I get an error saying:

> <Future at 0x1ba9696bb08 state=finished raised TypeError>

When I try to iterate over rlist, I get an error saying:

> TypeError: 'Future' object is not iterable

What am I doing wrong? How do I go about this?